# spark sampleBy behavior, is it deterministic - same input will get same output when you provide seed?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using [sampleBy()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy) get [stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling) on a spark dataframe.

```
samples = df.sampleBy("label", fractions, seed=314156)
```

df is a dataframe with a `label` column, (as the name implies it is the label of each row) and the fractions is a dictionary of `{label:fraction}` as what is documented. the dataframe is always loading data from same set of csv files (stored in s3), the fractions is also determistic (same each time).

this is the behavior i get, the output is deterministic (weakly indicated by `samples.count()`) on my local machine with pyspark 2.4 (local mode). but i get different results on EMR (pyspark 2.3 yarn).

so my question is what is the guarantee of `sampleBy` when you provide the seed? how to make the result deterministic? same cluster? or same partition numbers?

Comment: At least in theory `sampleBy` should be as deterministic as the parent object - in your case `df`. In other words - if there are no non-deterministic operations upstream (like shuffles) and input format loads data in a deterministic order and the configuration is used the result should be reproducible. So there are _many_ moving parts, and seed alone is definitely not enough.

Comment: so what makes the dataframe `same` for `sampleBy`?  are different partition numbers count as different or same? will sort make it deterministic (provide it's the same ondisk persistent dataset)? is there any document reference? thanks. @user10938362

Comment: Different partition count is one factor. Different order of values in partition another.  Both can differ depending on a number of factor though most of these should be solved by using the same configuration. As of sort, I wouldn't bet on that. Since sorting requires initial sampling, this might (?) vary from run to run. Though repartition and sort within partitions, using _unique_ and _deterministic_ expression should work. I am not aware of any official docs, but if you follow the source you should get a basic idea `sampleBy` -> `functions.rand` -> `Rand` -> per partition seed.

Comment: thanks for the insight, let me do some more experiments with repartitions and sort partitions. and at least the result in different env are deterministic meaning multirun of sampleBy on the same dataset in cluster or local dev are deterministic but cannot cross environment. which might because the loading are deterministic within the same environment.

Comment: @user10938362 please add your comment as answer i can accept it. yes experiment shows that `repartition` then `sortWithinPartitions` works.